# Trying to connect Coldfusion 9 to a MYSQL Datasource that was installed via MAMP (free) is throwing an error

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, mamp, coldfusion-9

I am trying to connect Coldfusion 9 to a MYSQL Database that was installed by MAMP (**free not Pro**) with the following parameters:

**CF Data Source Name:** MyDatasource

**Database:** MyDatabase

**Server:** localhost

**Port:** 8889

**Username:** root

**Password:** root

In the coldfusion Administrator I can successfully connect to this database. However, when I try to display a .cfm page that has a connection to that datasource, this error is thrown:

```
Error Executing Database Query.
Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Any ideas??

Any help would be immensely appreciated!!

**edit**

this is what MAMP wants me to use and it did create a successful connection in CF Admin.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after searching and trying to figure out what is going on, I decided to check my Application.cfm file, and sure enough, I have global connection strings for all of my queries.  One of those strings was the DB password, which was not set to "root".. Thank you for your help and I apologize for the stupid question..

Answer (score 1):

In the CF admin, if you click "Verify" it shows a successful connection?  Usually MySQL databases are on port 3306 not 8889.  Are you sure you have the correct settings?

Comment: Yep, when I click the 'Verify' button in CF Admin it sets the Status to 'OK' .. this is really odd.  And, usually MySQL is on port 3306, but according to MAMP, they want me to use 8889.  I have updated my question to show the MAMP screen shot.